# Java variable undefined but it is define at the beginning

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, java.util.scanner

My code is to convert some integer number in there Roman equivalent. Say integer 5 is Roman equivalent "V" and so on. I am using switch case for conversion. But it throws an error that the variable symbol which is a string type variable , this is undefined. I declare this variable at the top of the code.

Conversion table is like that:

```
 Symbol       Value
  I             1
  V             5
  X             10
  L             50
  C             100
  D             500
  M             1000
import java.util.Scanner;

//Integer to Roman Conversion
public class integer_roman {
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the Integer number");
    int number= in.nextInt();
    String symbol;
    switch (number){
        case 1:
            symbol="I";
            break;
        case 5:
            symbol="V";
            break;
        case 10:
            symbol="X";
            break;
        case 50:
            symbol="L";
            break;
        case 100:
            symbol="C";
            break;
        case 500:
            symbol="D";
            break;
        case 1000:
            symbol="M";
            break;
    }
    System.out.println(symbol);
}
}
```

Error: Error:(34, 28) java: variable symbol might not have been initialized

I cannot figure out the problem. If anyone have any idea then please share that.

Comment: The compiler can not guarantee that `symbol` is assigned a value by the time it's used. Local variables are NOT assigned a default value, therefore they are "undefined".  Assign a "default" to the local variable when you define it

Comment: "not initialized" != "undefined" !! "not initialized" means it has not got an (initial) value; "undefined" means it was not defined or declared. Since there is no `default` in your switch, the variable may end without any value -> error not initialized. A `switch` is probably not the best fit for your case (assuming something here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
String symbol;
```

is the declaration of the variable `symbol` but it does not do any initialization.  
Later the `switch` block does not cover every possible value that the variable `number` could have so there is a case that `symbol` would remain uninitialized even after the `switch` block.  
This is why the compiler complains, because it is not possible for an uninitialized variable to be printed or used at the right side of an assignment. 
It's better to initialize it at the beginning this way:

```
String symbol = "undefined";
```

so if in the `switch` block `symbol` does not get any value, `undefined` will be printed.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly print the message to the user and then get his input with `Scanner`.

Secondly add a `default:` where you initialize the `symbol` in case the user typed something else except the defined cases in the switch-statement.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Enter the Integer number");
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);

        int number= in.nextInt();
        String symbol = null;
        switch (number){
            case 1:
                symbol="I";
                break;
            case 5:
                symbol="V";
                break;
            case 10:
                symbol="X";
                break;
            case 50:
                symbol="L";
                break;
            case 100:
                symbol="C";
                break;
            case 500:
                symbol="D";
                break;
            case 1000:
                symbol="M";
                break;
            default:
                symbol="Uknown number."
        }
        System.out.println(symbol);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for that helpful discussion. There is so many theories about defining the string in which I am taken null.

```
String symbol=null;
```

It works well. I don't know a variable can define with undefined or null values. So I am confused. But there is no need to downgrade this post. I write down a whole code. Only stuck in one point.